# Podio - customize webhook request data

Tags: podio

When a Podio webhook is triggered by its subscribed event, the hook will send a request to an external url with information about that event.  Is it possible to customize the information contained in the request?

For example, I am planning to create a webhook that will be triggered when an app field is updated.  The default webhook settings will include

```
body: { item_id: '12345',
        item_revision_id: '2',
        type: 'item.update',
        hook_id: 54321' }
```

in the request.  However, this means that I have to chain this to another `GET` request back to Podio if I want to get more information about the updated item (these are 'user' items, so I want things like 'first_name', 'last_name', etc.).

When I create a hook via the API (https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks/create-hook-215056), is there a way that I can customize it so that the entire updated item record is included in the requests when the hook is called?  In the Ruby and PHP client examples, there's an `attributes` parameter - can you set the request data via `attributes` and, if so, how should that be formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to customize Podio webhook request. Each and every Podio webhook has same structure, and if you need more information about item being updated/created you will need to fire another `GET` request.